# What's the usage of items when creating box, tab, or group

Tags: syntax, dialog, dm-script

When I create the containers, such as tab, box or group, one of the argument is container_items. At first, I always created container_items. And I think I must use container_items.DLGAddElement() to add element. But I found I can achieve the same result by using container.DLGAddElement().

Also, for some widget, like radio button, it also has container_items argument.

Could anyone give me some information when will we use the contain_items?

```
DLGCreateTab( TagGroup &tab_items, string label )
DLGCreateBox( String title, TagGroup &items )
DLGCreateGroup( TagGroup &items )
DLGCreateRadioList( TagGroup &items )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Nearly) all DLG... commands are essentially utility methods that build a tagGroup, where the tagGroup describes what the dialog will be like. For debugging or learning purpose it is often helpful to show this tagGroup. If different commands yield the same tagGroup, they indeed are identical in function.

To display a TagGroup, you can use

`TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(tagGroup myTags, string Name, bool isFileBased)`

with `mytags` being the TagGroup to be displayed (the one you create with DLGCreateDialog)
and

with `Name` just being the title of the shown dialog and

with `isFileBased` indicating whether or not the tags (if changed) should be saved once the dialog is closed.

---

```c
number addToContainer = 1

string infoStr = "Items added to " + (addToContainer?"Container":"ContainerItems")

taggroup dlg, dlgItems
dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Test",dlgItems)

taggroup box, boxItems
box = DLGCreateBox("Box 1",boxItems)

if ( addToContainer )
{
    box.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(infoStr))
    dlg.DLGAddElement(box)
}
else
{
    boxItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(infoStr))
    dlgItems.DLGAddElement(box)
}

dlg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(infoStr,0)

Alloc(UIFrame).Init(dlg).Display(infoStr)
```

gives you[image: Results]:

As you can see, both methods give you the same dialog and (nearly) the same tag structure, but adding to the container instead of the container items tags adds an "invalid" flag. I would guess, adding to the items is the "correct" way, but when adding to the container itself, the underlying code 'fixes' it for your. Quite likely some convenience behavior added at later state.

---

Example regarding comment on tabs:

```c
taggroup dlg,dlgitems
dlg=DLGCreateDialog("Dialog",dlgitems)

taggroup box,boxitems
box=DLGCreateBox("Box",boxitems)
box.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Just some boxy stuff"))

dlgitems.DLGAddElement(box)

taggroup tablist1,tabitems1
tablist1=DLGCreateTabList(tabItems1)

taggroup tab1 = tabitems1.DLGAddTab("Tab1")
tab1.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Page #1"))

taggroup tab2 = tabitems1.DLGAddTab("Tab2")
tab2.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Page #2"))
dlgitems.DLGAddElement(tablist1)


taggroup tablist2,tabitems2
tablist2=DLGCreateTabList(tabItems2)

taggroup tab3 = tabitems2.DLGAddTab("Tab3")
tab3.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Page #3"))

taggroup tab4 = tabitems2.DLGAddTab("Tab4")
tab4.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("Page #4"))
dlgitems.DLGAddElement(tablist2)


dlg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("Tab",0)
Alloc(UIFrame).Init(dlg).pose()
```

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'm writing some python code to automatically generate the ui elements code. If adding to container directly, the python code will be much easier.

Comment: One more question about the container type. For box and group, we just need to add the elements into the container which is created by DLGCreateBox or DLGCreateGroup. But for tab and panel, we need to further add the elemets into the tablist or panellist. Then we can add the tablist or panellist into dialogue. Of course we just need to add one line command. But is there any reason to do that? If tablist is high level container than tab, is that means we can add several tablist to one dialogue?

Comment: @ChenZX: You can have multiple tabs in a dialog, yes. (see added example). A tab is an element (like a box) that contains "pages" (the tab-items). The pages themselves are containers that contain other dialog items just like the primary dialog does. I think the structure makes sense as it is.